# VueJS SFC and DOM

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm looking to try and achieve something which I believe *should* be possible, however, currently I've not been able to achieve it nor find any material which points in the right direction!

Ideally, I would like to build a set of components through SFC's (.vue files) and have these compiled. In terms of using these components, they should be able to be placed on an existing HTML page, and additional HTML passed into the component through the use of `slot`. I've already got the latter theory working through compiled SFC's and the Vue-CLI "App" component that is included. This obviously works by drawing all content into `<div id="app">...`, ideally I need to get away from this and end up with the following:

```
<body>
   <div id="app">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-4">
             <filters></filters> <!-- "Filter" component -->
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-8">
             <result-list>
                 <div>I'm a result template!</div>
             </result-list>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

The overall page would be using Vuex to handle state between the two modules. Currently if I try changing `main.js` (included as part of `vue-cli create .`) from:

```
new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

to:

```
new Vue({
  store,
  components: {
    ResultList
  },
  el: "#app"
});
```

This results in a console error:

> Unknown custom element <result-list> did you register the component correctly?

My initial reading suggests this is because everything has been compiled and so Vue can't recognise the element, but I have changed the `vue.config.js` file to ensure `runtimeCompiler` is set to `true`, unfortunately this does not help in the slightest.

Can anybody point me in the right direction, perhaps examples of where this approach may have been done in the past, or if I'm going completely mad and it's actually not possible?

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: Adding it to the `components` section should be sufficient. Are you sure that the error message references `<result-list>` and not `<filters>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it would appear that after actually sleeping I managed to work it out.

@skirtle you were correct in that it's because I wasn't exposing the components as global components. By changing the way in which my app mounts I was able to get the result that I needed. I'm now of the opinion when I can compile all components, but then expose those that I wish to be usable through static HTML.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  components: {
    'result-list': ResultList
  }
})
```

This now allows for `<result-list>` to be used in the HTML dynamically within the `#app` container.